# Preventing use of "Back" on iOS and Android

Tags: flutter

My app has a "More" screen with a bunch of buttons, one button is Sign Out. My Sign Out button logs them out of Firebase and pushes the Sign In screen to the user.

But, if they simple swipe from the left on iOS, or hit the back button on Android, they are right back at the "More" screen where the Sign Out button is. I need to prevent this "Back" action.

I have tried using WillPopScope, without success.

I am using persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2 for my bottom nav, and so I am using one of their functions to push the Sign In screen, since I need to push it without the bottom nav bar.

```
                            WillPopScope(
                              onWillPop: () async => false,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                                  pushNewScreen(
                                    context,
                                    screen: SignIn(),
                                    withNavBar: false, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
                                    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width: inputWidth - 15,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                      Radius.circular(10)),
                                                  color: Color(0xFFf6f4fe),
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                    color: Color(0xFFc1b8f4),
                                                    width: 1,
                                                  )
                                              ),
                                              width: 40,
                                              height: 40,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                  'assets/images/sign_out.svg',
                                                  semanticsLabel: 'Sign Out Image',
                                                  color: Color(0xFF39393a),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                                          Text("Sign Out",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SvgPicture.asset(
                                        'assets/images/arrow_small.svg',
                                        semanticsLabel: 'Arrow Image',
                                        color: Color(0xFF39393a),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: could you add the full code of More screen?

Comment: I think that you would not want to stop user from going back. The correct method will be to use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(...your route)` and then back press will allow you to exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was using WillPopScope incorrectly, it needs to be applied to the Sign In screen.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SetSizes();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                          [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      SvgPicture.asset(
                                          'assets/images/logo.svg',
                                          semanticsLabel: 'Pearmonie Logo'
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 15),
                                SignInArea(),
                              ],
                            ),]))])
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```